# How to sort Sass properties (for example in alphabetical order)

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I need gulp module, or vscode extension for example, which can sort properties in .sass files automaticaly.

I know sort-sass npm module but I can't automate it (it works in CLI, so i tried to run it from gulp-exec module)

need from this:

```
text-decoration: none
margin: 0 auto
justify-content: space-between
text-transform: uppercase
width: 500px
align-items: center
color: black
padding: 100px
background-color: white
z-index: 5
height: 100px
display: flex
```

to this:

```
display: flex
justify-content: space-between
align-items: center
height: 100px
width: 500px
padding: 100px
margin: 0 auto
background-color: white
color: black
text-decoration: none
text-transform: uppercase
z-index: 5
```

(put on personal preferences, not necessary like this)

---

Now I'm using stylelint with autofixing, that's cool.

Comment: Did you try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-csscomb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, [Tien Duong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11769253/tien-duong). I installed CSSComb in vscode, works great after I made a config (needed some time to sort out how it works. Now my properties sorts each time I save file)